# php preg_match - particular cyrillic chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

We have a:

```
preg_match('/^([А|В|Е|К|М|Н|О|Р|С|Т|У|Х].)(?:[\d]{3})(?:[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ].){2}(?:[\d]{2,3})$/', 'Ф123АХ123');
```

reg exp, but it didn't work either with 1-st input and second non-greedy.

I've tried also with UTF-8 hex code, but it hasn't worked, :

```
preg_match('/^([x\{0445}x\{0446}].)(?:[\d]{3})(?:[x\{0445}x\{0446}].){2}(?:[\d]{2,3})$/u', 'Х123ЦЦ123');
```

Just remember it is Cyrillic - magic Russian chars =)

Any help, especially concrete - will be appreciated.

Comment: This `[А|В|Е|К|М|Н|О|Р|С|Т|У|Х]` should be `[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]` (you got it right second time). Also, add the `u` (=utf8) flag to your expression.

Comment: I've already tried this and that and with `[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]` everywhere - not working if You write say: Ц or Щ - it detects this as TRUE as this is in range, but it is not, I do not want other symbols get matched, but they are if `[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]` - even with `.`, which means just one symbol.

Comment: Have you added `u` to it?

Comment: Are U talking about 1st or 2nd regexp? I've added it only to 2nd and now tried for 1st - everything is false now ex.: Р123СР123, I presume /u flag is only needed when x\{0445} used.

Comment: Ok, I feel we're somehow lost in translation here... answered below.

Comment: Unless your source and the input is somehow encoded in 1 byte character set (Windows-1251 for example), using Cyrillic character in non-UTF mode (without `u`) will not do what you want, since the engine is seeing the bytes making up the Cyrillic characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you're looking for:

```
/^([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ])(\d{3})([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2})(\d{2,3})$/u
```

Examples:

```
preg_match('/^([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ])(\d{3})([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2})(\d{2,3})$/u', 'Ф123АХ123', $m);
print_r($m); // nothing, because Ф doesn't match

preg_match('/^([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ])(\d{3})([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2})(\d{2,3})$/u', 'У123АХ123', $m);
print_r($m); // matches
```

As a general advice, when using pcre with non-latin inputs, make sure that

- your inputs are utf8 encoded
- your sources are utf8 encoded
- you're using the "u" flag in your regexes